# Show ACF from post to category template

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom field (text field) inside my posts and I want to show the value of the field into the category template. I am new to ACF and any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/ See `Get a value from a specific post`

Comment: I want to show to the fields values of all the posts that belong to the specific category into the category template. ex. I want all the products that belong to the Offers category to have a retail price and web price

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so maybe do something like this if you want to loop through everything. Change 'field_name' to your field's name in the ACF part of the back end.

```
<?php
$cat = get_the_category();
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => $cat, 'post_type' => 'post', );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
     // Assuming you want the link/title to the post
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>

      // Display the custom field value
      <?php echo get_field('field_name'); ?>
     </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```